# OrientDB inconsistent behavior calling reload()

Tags: orientdb

I have encountered a strange problem. I load a Vertex and after, at some point, I call to reload() to refresh the data and I get ORecordNotFoundException. The vertex exist because the get() has retrieved it. Why reload fail?
All of this is executed over the same tx.
Even worse, sometime it fail, sometime it work. When I run the tests, sometimes all pass and sometime one fail. All the test are self contained. Each test create an entity, store it, dereference it, get a new instance and test if all is fine.
Could be because the Tx is never closed? I call commits/rollbacks over the tx many time but only call to shutdown at the end.
All of this is tested against OrientDB 3.0.7

Comment: Hi, probably it's a problem because it's all executed over the same Tx. Maybe try to close the Tx

Comment: Now I open/close each tx but the problem reamins. And always randomly.